# How do I make these files in DOSBOX...Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

Ok people...
I'm working with TASM and DOSBOX to make a specific code work.
Now the thing is I need several files to make.
.exe .sbr .crf .lst .asm .map .obj

I was able to create all except .crf and .sbr

How do I do them? Please help

This is the code....

```
TITLE PROG2-3 (EXE) PURPOSE: TRANSFERS 6 BYTES OF DATA PAGE 60,132
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64

.DATA
ORG 10H
    DATA_IN DB 25H, 4FH, 85H, 1FH, 2BH, 0C4H
ORG 28H
    COPY DB 6 DUP (?) ;--------------

.CODE 
MAIN PROC FAR
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV SI, OFFSET DATA_IN
    MOV DI, OFFSET COPY
    MOV CX, 03H

    MOV_LOOP:
    MOV Ax, [SI]
    MOV [DI], Ax
    INC SI
    INC SI
    INC DI
    INC DI
    DEC CX
    JNZ MOV_LOOP

    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
MAIN ENDP

END MAIN
```

Comment: What should those files (.crf & .sbr) contain?

Comment: Well he said the codes I just put should make those file (sbr and crf) automatically after being run. But after doing so in TASM and DOSBOX it didn't

Comment: _"Well he said"_. Who did? And what instructions did that person provide? What are the exact commands you're using to build your execuatble?

Comment: My professor said just input the codes as provided and provide these 7 files mentioned. That's all I know. If I knew I wouldn't be here would I?

Well since it's DOSBOX and TASM

I do.... TASM A.ASM
TLINK A.OBJ

This creates the exe but not crf or sbr....I don't know how to do them

Comment: If you don't know what they are for, why do you need them?

Comment: That's strange. `.crf` is the cross reference file of MASM5. `.sbr` is the browser info file of MASM6. Neither can MASM5 produce a `.sbr` file nor can MASM6 produce a `.crf` file. In TASM  a cross reference file is the 4th file: `TASM name,,,name` (without extensions) will produce a `.xrf` file.

Answer (score 0):

.crf is a cross reference. MASM will create a cross reference in a separate .crf file. With TASM, as I recall, the cross reference is added to the .lst file if you specify /c on the command line.

.sbr is a source browser file. Again, MASM would create these files for use with the debugger. I think the corresponding option in TASM was /zi, which would create full debugging info. But I don't think it created a .sbr file.

You might try typing `tasm /?` on the command line and see if it outputs a command line options reference. Or ask your professor.